# Spring dispatcher url pattern not working

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

Mapping to a controller method is not working. Going to `http://localhost:8080/teleseminars/telesem_live` returns a 404 and this shows up in the logs:

> 2012-10-30 11:37:58,190 [http-8086-1] [WARN ]
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.noHandlerFound(DispatcherServlet.java:947)]
>   No mapping found for HTTP request with URI
>   [/teleseminars/telesem_live] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcher'

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the controller:

```
@Controller
public class TeleseminarsController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value= "/teleseminars/{page}/{series}", method = RequestMethod.GET) ///{page}/{series}
    public String getTele(@PathVariable("page") String page,
            @PathVariable("series") String series,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            final Model model) {

                //do stuff

            return page;
    }
}
```

I have this on web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/teleseminars/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Why do you have `*.do` mapping in your `servlet-mapping`? One `url-pattern` with `/*` should be enough - all requests will then be dispatched to Spring MVC.

Comment: Thanks, @romario333 - Other methods we have are using the .do extension. This would map every URI to the spring dispatcher, which of course I cannot do. I've tried that in the past and it takes on ALL requests. All images, css, js, html, etc. all get dispatched to Spring...

Answer (score 2):

The `servlet-mapping` you have eats that part of it. In your controller you may have to change the `@RequestMapping` to `@RequestMapping(value= "/{page}/{series}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`. I have had that problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping two path variables, hence `http://localhost:8080/teleseminars/telesem_live/foo` would match, but `http://localhost:8080/teleseminars/telesem_live` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, but tried that and got: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/teleseminars/telesem_live/SB_0] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Answer (score 0):

could you please make sure the following line is available in your context.xml

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourapp.controller" />
```

In Spring 3 or above, you still need to enable “auto component scanning” (for controller) and declares “view resolver” manually.I too experienced this problem sometime ago.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I already have that set. Mappings to *.do are working great.